# How to concatenate the values from the loop and save into a single file?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to loop through the country list and pass the country name to the link and fetch the information from a website.

Right now, my code only saves the data pertaining to the last iteration of the country list into a file. How do I save data from all the countries on my loop into my file?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests
import pandas as pd
ctry_list = ["afghanistan","albania"]
for ctry in ctry_list:
    url = "https://www.cia.gov/resources/world-leaders/foreign-governments/"+ctry
    page = requests.get(url)
    page.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    data = []
    pep_list={}
    for e in soup.select('.leader-info'):
        d = {
            'country':ctry,
            'title':e.h4.text,
            'first_name':' '.join([s for s in e.p.text.split() if not s.isupper()]),
            'last_name':' '.join([s.capitalize() for s in e.p.text.split() if s.isupper()])
        }
        data.append('|'.join(d.values()))
        pep_list = ('|'.join(d.values()))
        print(pep_list)
   
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        df.to_csv(f'output_files/FILE.txt',index=False)
```

Comment: move the last two lines outside the for loop

Comment: You can define a list then append the `df` to that list and use `pd.concat` out of the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests
import pandas as pd
ctry_list = ["afghanistan","albania"]

dfs = {}  # <- HERE
for ctry in ctry_list:
    url = "https://www.cia.gov/resources/world-leaders/foreign-governments/"+ctry
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    data = []
    pep_list={}
    for e in soup.select('.leader-info'):
        d = {
            'country':ctry,
            'title':e.h4.text,
            'first_name':' '.join([s for s in e.p.text.split() if not s.isupper()]),
            'last_name':' '.join([s.capitalize() for s in e.p.text.split() if s.isupper()])
        }
        data.append(d)  # <- HERE
    dfs[ctry] = pd.DataFrame(data)  # <- HERE
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=0, ignore_index=True)  # <- HERE
df.to_csv(f'output_files/FILE.txt',index=False)  # <- HERE
```

Output:

```
>>> df
        country                                              title                first_name       last_name
0   afghanistan                             Overall Taliban Leader                Akhundzada     Haybatullah
1   afghanistan                                         Prime Min.  Mohammad Akhund (Acting)          Hassan
2   afghanistan                                  Deputy Prime Min.            Abdul (Acting)           Kabir
3   afghanistan                                  Deputy Prime Min.      Abdul Ghani (Acting)         Berader
4   afghanistan                                  Deputy Prime Min.      Abdul Salam (Acting)          Hanafi
5   afghanistan                                    Min. of Defense         Mohammad (Acting)           Yaqub
6   afghanistan                                    Min. of Economy         Mohammad (Acting)        Qari Din
7   afghanistan                                  Min. of Education             Agha (Acting)      Habibullah
8   afghanistan                            Min. of Foreign Affairs        Amir Khan (Acting)          Motaqi
9   afghanistan                               Dir. of Intelligence        Abdul Haq (Acting)           Wasiq
10  afghanistan                                   Min. of Interior       Sirajuddin (Acting)         Haqqani
11  afghanistan                                    Min. of Justice      Abdul Hakim (Acting)          Sharai
12  afghanistan  Min. of Preaching, Promotion of Virtue, & Prev...         Mohammad (Acting)          Khalid
13      albania                                              Pres.                    Bajram           Begaj
14      albania                                         Prime Min.                       Edi            Rama
15      albania  Dep. Prime Min. and Min. of Infrastructure & E...                   Belinda         Balluku
16      albania            Min. of Agriculture & Rural Development                     Frida          Krifca
17      albania                                    Min. of Culture                      Elva       Margariti
18      albania                                    Min. of Defense                      Niko         Peleshi
19      albania                 Min. of Education, Sports, & Youth                      Evis           Kushi
20      albania                  Min. for Europe & Foreign Affairs                      Olta          Xhacka
21      albania                          Min. of Finance & Economy                    Delina        Ibrahimi
22      albania                    Min. of Health & Social Welfare                    Orgeta     Manastirliu
23      albania                                   Min. of Interior                    Bledar            Cuci
24      albania                                    Min. of Justice                      Ulsi           Manja
25      albania                   Min. of State for EU Integration                  Majlinda           Dhuka
26      albania      Min. of State for Protection of Entrepreneurs                     Edona          Bilali
27      albania        Min. of State for Relations With Parliament                     Elisa       Spiropali
28      albania             Min. of State for Standards & Services                     Milva         Ekonomi
29      albania                 Min. of State for Youth & Children                      Bora         Muzhaqi
30      albania                      Min. of Tourism & Environment                    Mirela  Kumbaro Furxhi
31      albania                 Min. of Transport & Infrastructure                    Edmond      Haxhinasto
32      albania                          Governor, Bank of Albania                      Gent           Sejko
33      albania                               Ambassador to the US                   Floreta           Faber
34      albania       Permanent Representative to the UN, New York                     Ferit           Hoxha
```